# How can I make this program check for multiple things one-at-a-time?

Tags: c#, if-statement

/*At the bottom of this code there are two if statements. I want to be able to check FIRST whether the user has selected a flavor(the text for the flavor textbox is "Select a flavor" by default). If they click the AddDrink button without selecting a flavor, the message box needs to show that they haven't selected a flavor, instead of haven't entered a quantity, and then proceed with the program. However, if they have chosen a flavor but haven't entered a quantity then it should show the message box about entering a quantity. If anymore info is needed please let me know. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!!*/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chap9DrinkApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ComputeCost_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCompleteOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lblFinalFlavor.Text + "\n" + lblFinalTopping.Text + "\n" + lblFinalCost.Text);
        }

        private void btnAddDrink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double cost = 0;
            double quantityPrice;
            double quantityNum;
            this.lblFinalTopping.Text = "Extras: ";

            if (this.radSmall.Checked)
            {
                cost += 3.00;
            }
            else if (this.radMedium.Checked)
            {
                cost += 3.50;
            }
            else if (this.radLarge.Checked)
            {
                cost += 4.00;
            }

            if (this.ckBoxCherries.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Cherries ";
            }
            if (this.ckBoxGrape.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Grapes ";
            }
            if (this.ckBoxLemon.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Lemon ";
            }
            if (this.ckBoxPineapple.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Pineapple ";
            }
            if (this.ckBoxStrawberry.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Strawberry ";
            }
            if (this.ckBoxVitamin.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Vitamin Pack ";
            }
            if (this.ckBoxWhipped.Checked)
            {
                cost += .50;
                this.lblFinalTopping.Text += "Whipped cream ";
            }

            this.lblFinalCost.Visible = true;            

            if (this.txtQuantity.Text != "0")
            {
                quantityNum = double.Parse(this.txtQuantity.Text);
                quantityPrice = cost * quantityNum;
                this.lblFinalCost.Text = "Cost: " + quantityPrice.ToString("c");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity!");

            if (this.cmboBoxJuiceFlav.Text != "Select a flavor")
                this.lblFinalFlavor.Text = "Flavor: " + this.cmboBoxJuiceFlav.Text;
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a flavor!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a real question, I believe this question is a kind of homework/task. Please research in MSDN Library before asking.

Comment: What gave it away?  The Chap9DrinkApp namespace perhaps? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what you want:

```
if (this.cmboBoxJuiceFlav.Text != "Select a flavor")
{
    this.lblFinalFlavor.Text = "Flavor: " + this.cmboBoxJuiceFlav.Text;
    if (this.txtQuantity.Text != "0")
    {
        quantityNum = double.Parse(this.txtQuantity.Text);
        quantityPrice = cost * quantityNum;
        this.lblFinalCost.Text = "Cost: " + quantityPrice.ToString("c");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity!");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a flavor!");
}
```

Comment: Yes this works too. But I'm still getting the quantity message box when clicking the flavor selection. I know it's because I'm calling the wrong event handler but I don't know any other way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: @jmendegan - Your flavour selection is a combobox and that's different from your `AddDrink` button so it sounds like this behaviour is correct. We'd have to see a screen shot to see what the right behaviour would be, but it sounds like you need to move some of your code to a different event handler.

Comment: Can you tell me a few things??? If this app lets a user customize a drink using checkboxes, radio buttons, and comboboxes, how should I place the code to save the user's choices and print them in a message box? Also, after they have added their choices to the order, how can I save their choices while allowing them to customize another drink? I'm thoroughly confused and need help quick! THANKS!

Comment: @jmendegan - I would create a `UsersDrinkChoices` class that know nothing about the check boxes, radio buttons, etc, but has methods that match the users actions on the UI. Something like `AddDrink`, `SelectDrink(int n)`, `SetQuantity(int n)`, etc. Whatever user action occurs on screen create methods into this class to build state. Also have methods for reading the values out. And, of course, this class would also let you know what errors there are. Maybe has `bool IsValid { get; }`, `string ErrorMessage { get; }`, etc. Does that help?

Comment: This helps some, yes. But I've done some research and got my program fully working. The only thing left to do now is add some type of database so I can save the user's choices while they customize multiple drinks. I've created a class called Orders and the values of their choices are passed into the class just fine. However when they choose to clear the form and start another drink, the values (even in the Orders class) are erased! I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: @jmendegan - It's time for you to post a new question with enough detail for someone to answer this last question. :-)

Comment: I finally got it!  Thanks anyway though. I know for a fact I'll be back asking more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

There's better ways to do what you're trying to do.  But just to get your problem solved, you could try this -

```
.
.
.
   string msgBoxTxt = "";

    if (this.txtQuantity.Text != "0")
    {
        quantityNum = double.Parse(this.txtQuantity.Text);
        quantityPrice = cost * quantityNum;
        this.lblFinalCost.Text = "Cost: " + quantityPrice.ToString("c");
    }
    else
        msgBoxTxt += "Please enter a quantity! ";

   if (this.cmboBoxJuiceFlav.Text != "Select a flavor")
       this.lblFinalFlavor.Text = "Flavor: " + this.cmboBoxJuiceFlav.Text;
   else
       msgBoxTxt += "Please select a flavor!";

   if (msgBoxTxt != "")
        MessageBox.Show(msgBoxTxt);
```

Comment: This works. However, when the program runs and you select a flavor it immediately shows the "Please enter a quantity" message box... I'll try messing around with it some more. But THANKS for your help!

Comment: That probably means your checkboxes are calling the btnAddDrink_Click event handler when they shouldn't.  If my answer is what you're looking for make sure you mark it as the correct answer, thanks :)

Comment: I'm just confused on which event handler it should be calling... This shouldn't be this hard (i know).

Comment: Well, at a guess, the only event that should be calling btnAddDrink_Click() is the click event for the btnAddDrink button.  The checkboxes don't have to call any event handler.  Think of it this way - do you really want to be calling btnAddDrink_Click() every time someone clicks on a checkbox?  Or do you only want to call it when they click on btnAddDrink?

Comment: Thanks for that. It clears some things up. HOWEVER, I thought putting everything inside btnAddDrink_Click would allow me to save the users drink orders when they chose to customize another drink. The scenario goes like this-- Program executes; User chooses small, medium, OR large; User selects flavor from combobox; User chooses extra toppings; User inputs quantity; User clicks Add Drink; User is prompted whether they want to add another order; If yes, form clears. If no, Complete My Order button shows up.